# How to set security header in response from azure Linux web hosting

Tags: .net, reactjs, web-config, webserver, httpwebresponse

I have hosted my Web Application on Azure in Linux environment. My web app is in `react` and services are created using `azure` function. Application written in .net framework to use krestel server.

When I have checked the Web Application URL by inserting in Security Headers it shows `F` means missing security header in response.

I want to add security header in response from server so that I could get `A+` on security headers.

But I am facing the issue as where to add these security header so that it reflects in response. How to add the security header config in code to mitigate security response header issue?

How shall I proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Any luck finding the answer?